# Publishing Approval Workflow with 2013 template

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

I wonder if we can create the publishing approval workflow with 2013 template. If not what is the workaround for that. When I create workflow using 2013 template certainly the option "Start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item." gets disabled. Is there any way we can enable it?

My query is limited with out of box SharePoint Designer workflow.

Comment: If the option gets displayed, can you not enable it? If it's an option you should be able to select/tick it.

Comment: I said option is disabled. it is visible but the check box is grayed out.